# How to collect DJ nativeswing jwebbrowser resource in JTabbedPane when a tab closed

Tags: java

recently,I have started working on a java application using `DJ NativeSwing` as my embed browser with `JTabbedPane model`.

A new window will open when I click some link and I will have new JWebbrowser instance each time. However, when I close a tab by `removeTabAt` provided by JTabbedPane, how can I collect the resource owned by the related JWebbrowser?

In my application, I try to execute `browser.getWebBrowserWindow().dispose();` and I get a NullPointerException. So I was wondering whether it will lead to memory leaks if I do nothing when a tab closed or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you create and destroy many web browsers, it is possible that memory increases. It generally depends on the quality of the native web browser that is used (old versions of IE were terrible). Some people work around that situation by closing the interface and re-opening it when the last web browser is closed, to make sure a new environment is ready for future web browsers (thus clearing all occupied memory).
To get the list of windows created by an instance of the web browser, you probably have to retain those references when opening the window which you can track by adding a web browser listener and listening to the windowWillOpen event. Maybe the example "JWebBrowser > Navigation Control" from the demo application would help.

Comment: Deckers,Thanks for your reply! I don't think that "closing the interface and re-opening it" may suitable for my application,for it will always open a webbrowser as main page.Let me explain how my application works.Several links in main page named A,B,C,etc. My application will click a link and open in a new tab and do some operation and then close it and back to main page and then repeat this procedure for the remaining links. When first started, my application works fine.But after a while,my browser crashed. So I wonder if  i can recollect its resources when I close a webbrowser?Thanks again.

Comment: If the browser crashes after loading many links, it is a problem with the browser. DJ Native Swing does not retain any data and relies on the native browser to do its job. In such situation, you should either not abuse the native web browser, or find one that does not crash, or work around the issue (like closing/reopening the interface).